# Determining inheritance relationships among type-erased classes

Tags: c++, c++11, type-erasure

I have a typical type-erasure setup:

```
struct TEBase
{
    virtual ~TEBase() {}
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
struct TEImpl : TEBase
{
    // ...
};
```

Now the question: Given a second class hierarchy like this,

```
struct Foo { };
struct Bar : Foo { };

struct Unrelated { };
```

is it possible, given a `TEBase * p`, to determine whether the dynamic type of `*p` is of the form `TEImpl<X>`, where, `X` derives from `Foo`? In other words, I want function:

```
template <typename T> bool is_derived_from(TEBase * p);
```

such that:

```
is_derived_from<Foo>(new TEImpl<Foo>) == true
is_derived_from<Foo>(new TEImpl<Bar>) == true

is_derived_from<Foo>(new TEImpl<Unrelated>) == false
```

In particular, I'm looking for a solution that is general, non-intrusive, and efficient. I've found two solutions to this problem (posted below as answers) but neither of them solve all three criteria.

Comment: All this is a bit silly. You could just have a `std::list<boost::any>` and erase when the `any_cast` succeeds. No need to reinvent several wheels.

Comment: @Luc: I'm not too familiar with Boost.TypeErasure (I'll look into it) but std::function<>::target only works with exact types. In the example, where I'm asking to run the predicate on all `Foo`s, I wouldn't be able to tell if a `Bar` matches.

Comment: @Kerrek: As far as I'm aware, any_cast only works on exact types, and so it won't work with inheritance.

Comment: @RickYorgason: Right, I thought that was the point? You give `DoPred` the *exact* type you want to match...

Comment: @RickYorgason: By the way, "type" is a terrible name for a member *object*. Usually the word "type" is used for member *types*, and very ubiquitously so...

Comment: @Kerrek: If you look at the expected output at the bottom, you're supposed to be able to give it a type, and it will run the predicate on any type which is *castable* to that type. I'll edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: I removed my misleading comment, I was thinking of the implementation of `target` (i.e. retrieving a `void*` to the payload), not its interface (which requires a type). AFAICT [here's documentation for Boost.TypeErasure](http://steven_watanabe.users.sourceforge.net/type_erasure/libs/type_erasure/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: I understand now. The question is extremely noisy; would you allow me to edit it to a more concise form?

Comment: @Kerrek: I would be thoroughly impressed if you could make it significantly more concise without losing important details, but if you think you can do it, go for it. You have a lot more experience with SO than I do.

Comment: @RickYorgason: OK, have a look. Feel free to roll back.

Comment: @Kerrek: Sums it up nicely. I've just put the criteria back in at the end.

Comment: @RickYorgason: I added some code that works with TR2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution involves comparing `typeid`s. `TEImpl` knows its own type, so it can check a passed `typeid` against its own.

The trouble is, this technique doesn't work when you add inheritance, so I'm also using template meta-programming to check if the type has `typedef super` defined, in which case it will recursively check its parent class.

```
struct TEBase
{
        virtual ~TEBase() {}

        virtual bool is_type(const type_info& ti) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct TEImpl : public TEBase
{
        bool is_type(const type_info& ti) {
                return is_type_impl<T>(ti);
        }

        template <typename Haystack>
        static bool is_type_impl(const type_info& ti) {
                return is_type_super<Haystack>(ti, nullptr);
        }

        template <typename Haystack>
        static bool is_type_super(const type_info& ti, typename Haystack::super*) {
                if(typeid( Haystack ) == ti) return true;
                return is_type_impl<typename Haystack::super>(ti);
        }

        template <typename Haystack>
        static bool is_type_super(const type_info& ti, ...) {
                return typeid(Haystack) == ti;
        }
};

template <typename T>
bool is_derived_from(TEBase* p)
{
        return p->is_type(typeid( T ));
}
```

For this to work with, `Bar` needs to be redefined as:

```
struct Bar : public Foo
{
        typedef Foo super;
};
```

This should be fairly efficient, but it's obviously not non-intrusive, since it requires a `typedef super` in the target class whenever inheritance is being used. The `typedef super` also has to be publicly accessible, which goes against what many consider to be a recommended practice of putting your `typedef super` in your private section.

It also doesn't deal with multiple-inheritance at all.

**Update:** This solution can be taken further to make it general and non-intrusive.

### Making it general

`typedef super` is great, because it's idiomatic and already used in many classes, but it doesn't allow multiple inheritance. In order to do that, we'll need to replace it with a type that can store multiple types, such as a tuple.

If `Bar` was rewritten as:

```
struct Bar : public Foo, public Baz
{
        typedef tuple<Foo, Baz> supers;
};
```

we could support this form of declaration by adding the following code to TEImpl:

```
template <typename Haystack>
static bool is_type_impl(const type_info& ti) {
        // Redefined to call is_type_supers instead of is_type_super
        return is_type_supers<Haystack>(ti, nullptr);
}

template <typename Haystack>
static bool is_type_supers(const type_info& ti, typename Haystack::supers*) {
        return IsTypeTuple<typename Haystack::supers, tuple_size<typename Haystack::supers>::value>::match(ti);
}

template <typename Haystack>
static bool is_type_supers(const type_info& ti, ...) {
        return is_type_super<Haystack>(ti, nullptr);
}

template <typename Haystack, size_t N>
struct IsTypeTuple
{
        static bool match(const type_info& ti) {
                if(is_type_impl<typename tuple_element< N-1, Haystack >::type>( ti )) return true;
                return IsTypeTuple<Haystack, N-1>::match(ti);
        }
};

template <typename Haystack>
struct IsTypeTuple<Haystack, 0>
{
        static bool match(const type_info& ti) { return false; }
};
```

### Making it non-intrusive

Now we have a solution which is efficient and general, but it's still intrusive, so it won't support classes that can't be modified.

To support this, we'll need a way to declare the object inheritance from outside the class. For `Foo`, we could do something like this:

```
template <>
struct ClassHierarchy<Bar>
{
        typedef tuple<Foo, Baz> supers;
};
```

To support that style, first we need the non-specialized form of ClassHierarchy, which we'll define like so:

```
template <typename T> struct ClassHierarchy { typedef bool undefined; };
```

We'll use the presence of `undefined` to tell whether or not the class has been specialized.

Now we need to add some more functions to TEImpl. We'll still reuse most of the code from earlier, but now we'll also support reading the type data from `ClassHierarchy`.

```
template <typename Haystack>
static bool is_type_impl(const type_info& ti) {
        // Redefined to call is_type_external instead of is_type_supers.
        return is_type_external<Haystack>(ti, nullptr);
}

template <typename Haystack>
static bool is_type_external(const type_info& ti, typename ClassHierarchy<Haystack>::undefined*) {
        return is_type_supers<Haystack>(ti, nullptr);
}

template <typename Haystack>
static bool is_type_external(const type_info& ti, ...) {
        return is_type_supers<ClassHierarchy< Haystack >>(ti, nullptr);
}

template <typename Haystack>
struct ActualType
{
        typedef Haystack type;
};

template <typename Haystack>
struct ActualType<ClassHierarchy< Haystack >>
{
        typedef Haystack type;
};

template <typename Haystack>
static bool is_type_super(const type_info& ti, ...) {
        // Redefined to reference ActualType
        return typeid(typename ActualType<Haystack>::type) == ti;
}
```

And now we have a solution which is efficient, general, and non-intrusive.

### Future solution

This solution meets the criteria, but it's still a little annoying to have to document the class hierarchy explicitly. The compiler already knows everything about the class hierarchy, so it's a shame that we have to do this grunt work.

A proposed solution to this problem is [N2965: Type traits and base classes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2965.html), which [has been implemented in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/api/a00909.html). This paper defines a `direct_bases` class, which is almost identical to our `ClassHierarchy` class, except its only element, `type`, is guaranteed to be a tuple, like `supers`, and the class is completely generated by the compiler.

So for now we have to write a little boilerplate to get this to work, but if N2965 gets accepted, we can get rid of the boilerplate and make TEImpl much shorter.

Special thanks to Kerrek SB and Jan Herrmann. This answer drew a lot of inspiration from their comments.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
template <typename Type, typename UnaryPredicate>
void DoPred(UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    if (T * p = dynamic_cast<Derived<T> *>(this))
    { 
        return pred(p->type);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This isn't 100% universal, since you cannot, for example, say `DoPred<int>`. A more universal solution would add a `virtual std::type_info type() const { return typeid(...); }` member function to the hierarchy and use *that* to determine if the type matches (the standard type erasure idiom). Both approaches use the same sort of RTTI, though.

---

After the clarification:

Right now, I don't think this can be solved. All you have is a `TEBase` subobject. It could be part of a `TEImpl<Bar>`, or part of a `TEImpl<Unrelated>`, but neither of those types is related to `TEImpl<Foo>`, which is what you're after.

You're essentially asking that `TEImpl<Bar>` *derives* from `TEImpl<Foo>`. To do this, you would actually want `TEImpl<T>` to *inherit* from all `TEImpl<std::direct_bases<T>::type>...`, if you see what I mean. This is not possible in C++11, but will be possible in TR2. GCC already supports it. Here is an example implementation. (It causes a warning due to ambiguous bases, which could be avoided with more work, but it works nonetheless.)

```
#include <tr2/type_traits>

struct TEBase { virtual ~TEBase() {} };

template <typename T> struct TEImpl;

template <typename TL> struct Derivator;

template <typename TL, bool EmptyTL>
struct DerivatorImpl;

template <typename TL>
struct DerivatorImpl<TL, true>
: TEBase
{ };

template <typename TL>
struct DerivatorImpl<TL, false>
: TEImpl<typename TL::first::type>
, Derivator<typename TL::rest::type>
{ };

template <typename TL>
struct Derivator
: DerivatorImpl<TL, TL::empty::value>
{ };

template <typename T>
struct TEImpl
: Derivator<typename std::tr2::direct_bases<T>::type>
{
};

template <typename T>
bool is(TEBase const * b)
{
  return nullptr != dynamic_cast<TEImpl<T> const *>(b);
}


struct Foo {};
struct Bar : Foo {};
struct Unrelated {};

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  TEImpl<int> x;
  TEImpl<Unrelated> y;
  TEImpl<Bar> z;
  TEImpl<Foo> c;

  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "int ?< Foo: " << is<Foo>(&x) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Unr ?< Foo: " << is<Foo>(&y) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Bar ?< Foo: " << is<Foo>(&z) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << "Foo ?< Foo: " << is<Foo>(&c) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: `this`, in this case, is a `Base*`. `type`, which is what needs to be passed into the predicate, is in `Derived`.

Comment: @Luc Danton: Thanks for your edit! I accidentally missed it because of concurrency :-S Added it now.

Comment: You got me really excited for a moment thinking that [the paper I mentioned earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853016/determining-inheritance-relationships-among-type-erased-classes?noredirect=1#comment24310534_16853375) was accepted into the standard. But it looks like GCC TR2 is just an incubator branch and doesn't actually represent the direction of C++ standardization. Am I wrong?

Comment: @RickYorgason: I'm not up to date with what's happening with TR2. I hear it's been abandoned. I'm also not sure whether `std::bases`/`std::direct_bases` will become standard, though I would hope so.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the article [Generic Programming:Typelists and Applications](http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-programmingtypelists-and-applica/184403813). There Andrei Alexandrescu desribes an implementation of a ad-hoc Visitor which should solve your problem. Another good resource would be his book [Moder C++ Design](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/modern-c-design/) where he describes a multidispatcher in a Brute Force way which uses the same approuch (pages 265 ...).

In my opinion these 2 resources are better for understanding than any code which could be printed here.

Comment: Ah, type lists. That still means explicitly documenting the class hierarchy somewhere, so it's not panacea, but I can't claim it doesn't solve the three criteria in the question.

Comment: @RickYorgason The problem with type erasure is that you have only the interface of the base type. If this is not sufficient you end up using one of the visitor variants, they are the other side of the medal: type recovery. The only non intrusive way I know are these ad-hoc visitation mechanisms and wait ... here is http://tinyurl.com/n3449 about type switching but I think it is not an easy thing (there was a wish to implement it for boost as GSOC project).

Comment: I've read that paper before, and I'd love the feature, but I'm not sure it would be helpful in this case. However, if we're open to language extensions, [Type traits and base classes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2965.html) would solve the problem perfectly.

Comment: @RickYorgason Now I realy understand your concern (with all updates of your question). Yes n2965 would help. For now I would let the users provide the list via a trait. I would provide a default implementation which forwards to a user provided implementation ( `struct trait<T> : trait_impl<T> {};` user provides `trait_impl`) and change the default to an compiler implemented trait von available.

Answer (score 0):

This solution involves abusing exceptions a bit. If the `TEImpl` type simply throws its data, `is_derived_from` can catch the type it's looking for.

```
struct TEBase
{
        virtual ~TEBase() {}

        virtual void throw_data() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct TEImpl : public TEBase
{
        void throw_data() {
                throw &data;
        }

        T data;
};

template <typename T>
bool is_derived_from(TEBase* p)
{
        try {
                p->throw_data();
        } catch (T*) {
                return true;
        } catch (...) {
                // Do nothing
        }
        return false;
}
```

This solution works great. It works perfectly with any inheritance structure, and it's completely non-intrusive.

The only problem is that it's no efficient at all. Exceptions were not intended to be used in this way, and I suspect this solution is thousands of times slower than other solutions.

Comment: It might not compile at all. Your `Type` needs to be default constructable to be thrown. And as you are writing a resource manager I doubt this will be the case.

Comment: You could throw/catch a pointer to your type (such as throw this).

Comment: Good point. I've updated the answer to throw a pointer instead, and to match the new question text.